# Update and insert record based on list of value in the parameter

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am using postgresql 9.3.

I want to create a function to update my table (flag='9') and insert new record (flag='0') with the rfidnumber specified in a parameter.

This parameter may have several value seperated by space (ie. 11 22 33 44)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fcreate_rfid (
  znumber varchar
)
RETURNS boolean AS
$body$
BEGIN
    --update old record which has the same rfid number and flag='9' if exists
    update tblrfid set flag='9' where flag='0' and rfidnumber in (znumber);

    -- generate new record
    insert into tblrfid(tanggal, flag, rfidnumber)
    select localtimestamp, '0', regexp_split_to_table(znumber, ' ');

     return true;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

when I call this function using:

```
select fcreate_rfid('11 22 33 44');
```

This function fails to update the old record, but success to insert the new record.

Help me to fixed this problem. I know the problem is the update command, but I just don't know to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do it in this way - `znumber` is a VARCHAR, not a list of elements. So the `IN` operator is useless here - you have only 1 element in the list and it is the whole string `znumber`, not its space-delimited elements.

I am not sure if the code below will work but it should give you some direction for your research:

```
UPDATE tblrfid SET flag='9' 
WHERE flag='0' AND rfidnumber = ANY (string_to_array(znumber,' '));
```